# Dynamic configuration inside initializer (devise by example)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm developing an Rails 4 app. Auth is against an MS ADFS.

This is my `config/initializers/devise.rb` (Only omniauth part)

```rb
config.omniauth :saml,
  issuer:                         "https://#{ENV['APP_HOST_AND_PORT']}",
  idp_sso_target_url:             "https://yyy.yyy.yyy/adfs/ls",
  assertion_consumer_service_url: "https://#{ENV['APP_HOST_AND_PORT']}/auth/saml/callback",
  name_identifier_format:         "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress",
  idp_cert: "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

This works fine but `APP_HOST_AND_PORT` need to be setted (of course.)

In this case, `APP_HOST_AND_PORT` match with HTTP host header + port, DNS domain + port... So I don't really need set this value. The app knows ( or will know ) this value.

But request.host (and request.port) or whatever aren't accessible yet.

There's an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why do you care about request information in the initializer? Initializers are loaded once when your app starts, so they have nothing to do with requests

Comment: @Joel_Blum, I know request is'nt available.  This is why I'm talking about dynamic configuration. Maybe the title is'nt clear. Maybe "Inside" is a wrong word. I wan't overwrite this config one time I know the value (with request.host or whatever)